# International Cybercrime Based in China. Who's Jurisdiction is it?

Tags: international, hacking, china, cryptography, crime

Quick question... I got my crypto wallet hacked.  I live in Canada.  Offender lives in China.  After the theft, he deposited the money into Huobi, whose HQ is also in China.  I did some preliminary emails to Chinese law enforcement after getting nowhere with Canadian authorities.  I got a reply from a Cybercrime group in China saying that this would fall under the jurisdiction of Canada, but I really don't believe that.  Does anybody know the answer?  Excerpts from Chinese Criminal Code would be preferred to back up statement.

Answer (score 4):

### China and Canada each have jurisdiction

If the RCMP want to, they can investigate the case, lay charges and seek extradition of the perpetrator from China. It will be refused. Therefore, they have wisely decided not to investigate.

If the Chinese authorities want to, they can investigate and lay charges in China against the perpetrator. However, that would potentially be embarrassing for China. Therefore, they have wisely decided not to investigate.

So, either country *could* prosecute but neither is going to.